# Partial std::hash specialization for const and non-const types

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, stdhash

I am having trouble with some code doing partial specialization of `std::hash` for one of my classes. Here's a self contained example.

***EDIT:*** Thanks Piotr, I changed the code to include the fixes but the error remains.

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>

class Base
{
public:
  template <class T>
  using const_pset = std::unordered_set<const T *, std::hash <T *>, std::equal_to <T *> >;
  template <class T, class U>
  using const_pmap = std::unordered_map<const T *, U, std::hash <T *>, std::equal_to <T *> >;
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
  std::size_t hash () const
  {
    std::hash<std::string> hashfn;
    return hashfn (str);
  }
  bool operator== (const A &a) const { return str == a.str; }
  std::string str;
};

namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct hash <A *>
    {
      typedef A argument_type;
      typedef std::size_t result_type;

      result_type operator () (const argument_type *op) const
      {
    return op->hash ();
      }
    };
    template <>
    struct hash <const A *>
    {
      typedef A argument_type;
      typedef std::size_t result_type;

      result_type operator () (const argument_type *op) const
      {
    return op->hash ();
      }
    };
};

extern const A* get_a ();

typedef Base::const_pmap<A, Base::const_pset<A> > mapA;

int
work (mapA &mapa)
{
  const A *a = get_a ();
  mapa[a];
  return 0;
}
```

If you compile it with (g++ 4.9.0):

```
$ g++ -std=gnu++11 -Wall -c test.cc 2>&1 | head -n 50
In file included from /tools/oss/packages/x86_64-rhel5/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/hashtable.h:35:0,
                 from /tools/oss/packages/x86_64-rhel5/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/unordered_set:47,
                 from test.cc:3:
/tools/oss/packages/x86_64-rhel5/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h: In instantiation of 'static bool std::__detail::_Equal_helper<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _HashCodeType, true>::_S_equals(const _Equal&, const _ExtractKey&, const _Key&, _HashCodeType, std::__detail::_Hash_node<_Value, true>*) [with _Key = const A*; _Value = std::pair<const A* const, std::unordered_set<const A*, std::hash<A*>, std::equal_to<A*>, std::allocator<const A*> > >; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Select1st; _Equal = std::equal_to<A*>; _HashCodeType = long unsigned int]':
/tools/oss/packages/x86_64-rhel5/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1707:23:   required from 'bool std::__detail::_Hashtable_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _Traits>::_M_equals(const _Key&, std::__detail::_Hashtable_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _Traits>::__hash_code, std::__detail::_Hashtable_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _Traits>::__node_type*) const [with _Key = const A*; _Value = std::pair<const A* const, std::unordered_set<const A*, std::hash<A*>, std::equal_to<A*>, std::allocator<const A*> > >; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Select1st; _Equal = std::equal_to<A*>; _H1 = std::hash<A*>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true>; std::__detail::_Hashtable_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _Traits>::__hash_code = long unsigned int; std::__detail::_Hashtable_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _Traits>::__node_type = std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const A* const, std::unordered_set<const A*, std::hash<A*>, std::equal_to<A*>, std::allocator<const A*> > >, true>]'
/tools/oss/packages/x86_64-rhel5/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/hashtable.h:1391:4:   required from 'std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::__node_base* std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::_M_find_before_node(std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::size_type, const key_type&, std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::__hash_code) const [with _Key = const A*; _Value = std::pair<const A* const, std::unordered_set<const A*, std::hash<A*>, std::equal_to<A*>, std::allocator<const A*> > >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const A* const, std::unordered_set<const A*, std::hash<A*>, std::equal_to<A*>, std::allocator<const A*> > > >; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Select1st; _Equal = std::equal_to<A*>; _H1 = std::hash<A*>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true>; std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::__node_base = std::__detail::_Hash_node_base; std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::size_type = long unsigned int; std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::key_type = const A*; std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::__hash_code = long unsigned int]'
/tools/oss/packages/x86_64-rhel5/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/hashtable.h:590:65:   required from 'std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::__node_type* std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::_M_find_node(std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::size_type, const key_type&, std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::__hash_code) const [with _Key = const A*; _Value = std::pair<const A* const, std::unordered_set<const A*, std::hash<A*>, std::equal_to<A*>, std::allocator<const A*> > >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const A* const, std::unordered_set<const A*, std::hash<A*>, std::equal_to<A*>, std::allocator<const A*> > > >; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Select1st; _Equal = std::equal_to<A*>; _H1 = std::hash<A*>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true>; std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::__node_type = std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const A* const, std::unordered_set<const A*, std::hash<A*>, std::equal_to<A*>, std::allocator<const A*> > >, true>; typename _Traits::__hash_cached = std::integral_constant<bool, true>; std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::size_type = long unsigned int; std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::key_type = const A*; std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::__hash_code = long unsigned int]'
/tools/oss/packages/x86_64-rhel5/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:597:60:   required from 'std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::mapped_type& std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = const A*; _Pair = std::pair<const A* const, std::unordered_set<const A*, std::hash<A*>, std::equal_to<A*>, std::allocator<const A*> > >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const A* const, std::unordered_set<const A*, std::hash<A*>, std::equal_to<A*>, std::allocator<const A*> > > >; _Equal = std::equal_to<A*>; _H1 = std::hash<A*>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true>; std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::mapped_type = std::unordered_set<const A*, std::hash<A*>, std::equal_to<A*>, std::allocator<const A*> >; std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, _Alloc, std::__detail::_Select1st, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits, true>::key_type = const A*]'
/tools/oss/packages/x86_64-rhel5/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/unordered_map.h:627:20:   required from 'std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = const A*; _Tp = std::unordered_set<const A*, std::hash<A*>, std::equal_to<A*>, std::allocator<const A*> >; _Hash = std::hash<A*>; _Pred = std::equal_to<A*>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const A* const, std::unordered_set<const A*, std::hash<A*>, std::equal_to<A*>, std::allocator<const A*> > > >; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::mapped_type = std::unordered_set<const A*, std::hash<A*>, std::equal_to<A*>, std::allocator<const A*> >; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::key_type = const A*]'
test.cc:61:9:   required from here
/tools/oss/packages/x86_64-rhel5/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1326:74: error: invalid conversion from 'const A*' to 'A*' [-fpermissive]
     { return __c == __n->_M_hash_code && __eq(__k, __extract(__n->_M_v())); }
                                                                          ^
In file included from /tools/oss/packages/x86_64-rhel5/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/functional:49:0,
                 from test.cc:1:
/tools/oss/packages/x86_64-rhel5/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/stl_function.h:339:7: note: initializing argument 1 of 'bool std::equal_to<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = A*]'
       operator()(const _Tp& __x, const _Tp& __y) const
       ^
In file included from /tools/oss/packages/x86_64-rhel5/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/hashtable.h:35:0,
                 from /tools/oss/packages/x86_64-rhel5/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/unordered_set:47,
                 from test.cc:3:
/tools/oss/packages/x86_64-rhel5/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1326:74: error: invalid conversion from 'type {aka const A*}' to 'A*' [-fpermissive]
     { return __c == __n->_M_hash_code && __eq(__k, __extract(__n->_M_v())); }
                                                                          ^
In file included from /tools/oss/packages/x86_64-rhel5/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/functional:49:0,
                 from test.cc:1:
/tools/oss/packages/x86_64-rhel5/gcc/4.9.0/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/stl_function.h:339:7: note: initializing argument 2 of 'bool std::equal_to<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = A*]'
       operator()(const _Tp& __x, const _Tp& __y) const
       ^
```

I can't understand why I am getting: `error: invalid conversion from 'const A*' to 'A*' [-fpermissive]`. 
Any suggestions on improving the code? It seems strange to have to specialize hash for both `A` and `const A` given the template body is the same.

Comment: start with: `bool operator== (const A &a) {}` -> `bool operator== (const A &a) const {}`

Comment: also, you are specializing `hash` for `A` and `const A` (`hash<A>`, `hash<const A>`), but eventually you use `hash<A*>` for a map that stores `const A*`

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, just noticed that I need to add const to the std::hash and std::equal_to parameters as well:

```
template <class T, class U>
  using const_pmap = std::unordered_map<const T *, U, std::hash <const T *>, std::equal_to <const T *> >
```

I am still happy to receive answers about improving the code.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote your specialization for `A`, but you use it with `A*`, so you need :

```
namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct hash<A*>
    {
      typedef const A* argument_type;
      typedef std::size_t result_type;

      result_type operator () (const argument_type op) const
      {
            return op->hash ();
      }
    };   
}
```

And your `std::unordered_map` is for `const A*` :

```
template <class T, class U>
using const_pmap = std::unordered_map<const T *, U, std::hash <T *>, std::equal_to <const T *> >;
```

But since `equal_to` calls `operator==` by default, you actually don't need it (unless you want to specialize it, too) :

```
class Base
{
public:
  template <class T>
  using const_pset = std::unordered_set<const T *, std::hash <T *> >;
  template <class T, class U>
  using const_pmap = std::unordered_map<const T *, U, std::hash <T *>>;
};
```

[**Compiled Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4583467ac9460247)

Comment: And as I mentioned before you also need `std::hash <const T *>`. Thanks.

Comment: @PauloJ.Matos : no you don't : ) see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a14a9be3ed522f09) for a working example